# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.checkpoint'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, modulenotfounderror

[this is the code. im executing this using spyder. and tried many versions of tensorflow but unable to solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLvMd.png)

[this is the error im getting. before i was gettng import error cannot import 'load_img'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt1Vv.png)

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the perfect question and how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), Complete and Verifiable Example.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had tensorflow 2.6.0 installed but tensorflow-estimator 2.10.0. The problem was solved by downgrading tensorflow-estimator:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-estimator==2.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tensorflow 2.5.0 installed and I solved the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.checkpoint` error in colab as follows:

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-estimator==2.5.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Download tensorflow before running your code.
`pip install tensorflow`